# NEST - Using GET instead of POST/PUT for searching

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Is there a way to tell NEST to use GET instead of POST when performing searches? Similar to how the ElasticSearch documentation shows CURL using GET I'd like to use GET when using NEST instead of using POST as it currently does.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/DSL/SearchDescriptor.cs line number 135

```
    public static void Update(IConnectionSettingsValues settings, ElasticsearchPathInfo<SearchRequestParameters> pathInfo, ISearchRequest request)
    {
        pathInfo.HttpMethod = request.RequestParameters.ContainsKey("source") ? PathInfoHttpMethod.GET : PathInfoHttpMethod.POST;
    }
```

Obviously you need to have `SearchRequest.RequestParameters.ContainsKey("source")` return `true` for it to do a `Get`.

In future. Just RTFM.

Comment: I went in and cloned their hub so I could try and figure out how to utilize this, but I wasn't able to figure out how to use this. How does one add a "source" key? Where does this "source" on the request come from? I've tried adding `.Fields(new[] { "*", "source" })` to my `client.Search<object>()` but it still sends out as POST over GET. Are you able to provide me with an example on how to do it?

My problem wasn't that the code didn't exist but that I haven't been able to find a valid way to trigger either that or any of the other places where GET might be replaced by POST.

Comment: According to this https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Nest/DSL/Common/BaseRequest.cs you need to set it in the QueryString.

Comment: Thanks for that, Aron. I'm still a bit confused as to how to get it to actually set this value, though. I manually compiled/used NEST where I changed the line mentioned above to force it to use GET in both cases and it still doesn't do what I'm looking for as the request body being sent by the GET is empty. I'm wondering if NEST can even do this as it doesn't send the request body along if it's doing a `SearchGet`.